# Button index in table,iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, tableview

I have `UIButtons` on each row of a `UITableView`.
How can I detect ,the button index (like we can detect the row index in table through `didSelectRowIndexAtIndexPath` method)?

Say for ex: I have a `UITableView` with custom `UITableViewCells`.
Out of 10 rows, 6 have `UIButtons`.

On button tap, I am taking user to next view(detail view).
But I am not able to get the `UIButton` (row) index.Since, I am taking user on button click not through `didSelectRowIndexAtIndexPath` method, I am not able to get the row index.

How can i get that?

Suggestion.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this in:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  //other code
  // your button reference here
  // if custom cell then use cell.yourbutton
  [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [button setTag:indexPath.row];
  //other code
}
```

Now buttons selector would belike this:

```
- (void)buttonPressedAction:(id)sender
{
   UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
   int row = button.tag;
}
```